# asBroadcastStream can't be called multiple times

Tags: dart

After the m4 update, where StreamController.broadcast() was removed, I've discovered that the asBroadcastStream can't be called multiple times. This means that you have to store the stream, as in the Ugly class, instead of just using a getter, as in the Pretty class.

Is this by design, or am I doing it wrong?

```dart
void main() {
  Pretty p = new Pretty();

  //This does not work.
  p.onChange.listen((n) => print(n));
  //This second call throws: "Bad state: Stream already has subscriber". Why?
  p.onChange.listen((n) => print(n));

  //This does work.
  Ugly u = new Ugly();
  u.onChange.listen((n) => print(n));
  u.onChange.listen((n) => print(n));
}

class Pretty{
  StreamController<int> _streamCtrl = new StreamController<int>();
  Stream<int> get onChange => _streamCtrl.stream.asBroadcastStream();
}

class Ugly{
  StreamController<int> _streamCtrl = new StreamController<int>();
  Stream<int> _onChange;
  Stream<int> get onChange => _onChange;

  Ugly(){
    _onChange = _streamCtrl.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no better way to do it.

Here is the thread from the mailing list, with more info: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/misc/asBroadcastStream%7Csort:relevance/misc/KJrKH5-bNkU/CjpIpEP_EpgJ

In the email, I said:

With r21499 we removed the StreamController.broadcast constructor.

> The StreamController.broadcast streams had nasty properties that could
>   easily lead to missed events and similar hard-to-debug conditions. We
>   initially added this class for the html-library, but ended up not
>   needing it there. By removing this class we can have a much cleaner
>   contract for Streams. We still kept the asBroadcastStream method. Its
>   behavior is slightly different and saner than the one of
>   StreamController.broadcast. In most cases you can try to migrate to
>   `asBroadcastStream` if you need to attach multiple listeners.

Comment: I'm guessing this is it for Dart 1.0 then? I think I read somewhere that the core libraries are considered stable since M4, so we're "stuck" with this for now? I can absolutely live with the ugly solution, but the pretty one is just sooo much more, well, pretty. :D

Comment: We can still do non-breaking changes.