# Creating Streams With Multiple Subscribers

Tags: dart

What is the best way to create and use streams with multiple subscribers?

It used to be:

```
new StreamController.broadcast()
```

But that constructor is gone in M4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per this link:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/KJrKH5-bNkU/CjpIpEP_EpgJ

> With r21499 we removed the StreamController.broadcast constructor.
>
> The StreamController.broadcast streams had nasty properties that could easily lead to missed events and similar hard-to-debug conditions.
>   We initially added this class for the html-library, but ended up not needing it there. By removing this class we can have a much cleaner contract for Streams.
>
> We still kept the asBroadcastStream method. Its behavior is slightly different and saner than the one of StreamController.broadcast.
>   In most cases you can try to migrate to `asBroadcastStream` if you need to attach multiple listeners.

So, create a new stream, and call `asBroadcastStream()` on it.

(But you might also want to keep an eye on this question: [asBroadcastStream can't be called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057001/asbroadcaststream-cant-be-called-multiple-times) )